# Flutter bottom navbar not being dynamic after I navigate from a specific page

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app i'm trying to set a bottom navigation bar for most of the screen. First of all I have created a TabsPage (Home, Search, ...) that includes a bottom nav bar and returns the chosen page by the selected index.

The problem is that once I navigate from HomePage to FoodPage the bottom navigation bar in FoodPage does not work as expected, it's just being static for now. I tried to create a buildPageContent method as I did in the TabsPage but it doesn't make sense because the FoodPage should refer to the index 0 (which is the HomePage index in the bottom nav bar).

To make things clear, here is some code:

**TabsPage.dart:**

```
class TabsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabsPage> createState() => _TabsPageState();
}

class _TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildPageContent(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return HomePage();
      case 1:
        return SearchRestaurantNewPage();
      /*  case 2:
        return Center(
          child: Text('Add Page'),
        ); */
      case 3:
        return ProfilePage();
      case 4:
        return PlusPage();
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: _buildPageContent(_currentIndex),
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTabTapped: _onTabTapped,
        ));
  }
}
```

**HomePage.dart: (This is how I navigate to FoodPage)**

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text("Food list",
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: screenHeight * 0.022,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => FavRestaurantsPage()));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "View all",
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      color: redColor, fontSize: screenHeight * 0.017),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

**This is FoodPage.dart:**

```
class FoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FoodPage> createState() => _FoodPage State();
}

class _FoodPage State extends State<FoodPage > {
 int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTabTapped(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar(
          currentIndex: currentIndex, onTabTapped: onTabTapped),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Food Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Food Page Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And finally this is my CustomBottomNavBar.dart:**

```
class CustomBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBottomNavBar(
      {Key? key, required this.currentIndex, required this.onTabTapped})
      : super(key: key);
  final int currentIndex;
  final Function(int) onTabTapped;

  @override
  State<CustomBottomNavBar> createState() => _CustomBottomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: redColor,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          currentIndex: widget.currentIndex,
          onTap: widget.onTabTapped,
          selectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(),
          unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(),
          items: [
            BottomNavBarItem.buildItem(
                "assets/icons/home.svg", 'Acceuil', widget.currentIndex, 0),
            BottomNavBarItem.buildItem(
                "assets/icons/search.svg", 'Découvrir', widget.currentIndex, 1),
            BottomNavBarItem.buildItem(
                "assets/icons/home.svg", null, widget.currentIndex, 2),
            BottomNavBarItem.buildItem(
                "assets/icons/user.svg", 'Profil', widget.currentIndex, 3),
            BottomNavBarItem.buildItem(
                "assets/icons/plus.svg", 'Plus', widget.currentIndex, 4),
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => SearchRestaurantNewPage()));
                },
                backgroundColor: redColor,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Using a buildPageContent method inside the FoodPage is not a good solution as I tried, because the FoodPage should refer to HomePage (index 0). Is there any way I can fix this issue? thanks in advance!